# empty returned rows in Hive query

Tags: json, mongodb, hive, cloudera

I have created an external Hive table from a tweets json file which is exported from Mongo DB. Whenever I select more than one column from the hive table, the retrieved results are not well formatted. some columns are empty or NULL (even if i conditioned on specific values)and some data appear in the wrong columns.

I think this is happening because the text has commas in it. when i try to query the hive table without selecting the text of the tweets, the results make sense then. But i don't know how to fix that.

Anyone Has any idea how to fix that??

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try formatting the output? Something like this -

```
    SELECT
CONCAT(COALESCE(COL1,''),
  '|', COALESCE(COL2,''),
  '|', COALESCE(COL3,''),
  '|', COALESCE(COL4,''),
  '|', COALESCE(COL5,''),
  '|', COALESCE(COL6,''),
  '|', COALESCE(COL7,'')) as tweetsout
FROM (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7
    FROM TWEETS
    ) TOUT
```

This would give you the output delimied by a pipe instead of the standard tab delimited output.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without knowing the exact `create table` command you used...

Usually the table is parsed incorrectly if the input data contains table delimiters. For example, some tweets in your input database may contain `\n` which might be a row separator in the hive table you created.